# Speeding up webpage parsing with splinter/selenium

Tags: python, multithreading, thread-safety, python-multithreading, splinter

I am trying to achieve something like below.

1. Use splinter to visit a URL
2. Passing the browser instance to all the methods using multiple process ( multiprocessing.Process )
3. All methods get executed in threads and the overall time is reduced

The sample code looks like below.

```
from splinter import Browser
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue, current_process, freeze_support

#
# Function run by worker processes
#

def worker(input, output):
    for func, args in iter(input.get, 'STOP'):
        result = calculate(func, args)
        output.put(result)

#
# Function used to calculate result
#

def calculate(func, args):
    print(args)
    result = func(*args)
    return '%s says that %s%s = %s' % \
        (current_process().name, func.__name__, args, result)


def get_meta_tag_title(browser):
    return browser.find_by_xpath('//title')[0]['text']

def get_meta_tag_description(browser):
    return browser.find_by_xpath('//description')[0]['text']

#
#
#

def test():
    browser = Browser(headless=True)
    browser.visit('https://example.com')
    NUMBER_OF_PROCESSES = 2
    TASKS1 = [(get_meta_tag_title, (browser)), (get_meta_tag_description, (browser))]

    # Create queues
    task_queue = Queue()
    done_queue = Queue()


    # Submit tasks
    for task in TASKS1:
        task_queue.put(task)

    # Start worker processes
    for i in range(NUMBER_OF_PROCESSES):
        Process(target=worker, args=(task_queue, done_queue)).start()

    # Get and print results
    print('Unordered results:')
    for i in range(len(TASKS1)):
        print('\t', done_queue.get())

    browser.quit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    freeze_support()
    test()
```

My questions are -

1. Is it correct approach?, Would it thread-safe to use the browser instance to get all the elements info/ values
2. Adding browser instance to Queue results in `TypeError: cannot serialize '_io.BufferedWriter' object` am I supposed to use Pool?

Comment: 1. You say in your question you are using threads, but your code is using processes.
2. Are you actually having performance issues? What is the bottleneck?

Comment: yeh, basically my code uses the browser instance to find a few things like meta tags, inline styles, internal links, social links, etc. I would like to make these functionals run concurrently to reduce the overall execution time.

Answer (score 1):

Splinter is base on selenium's `WebDriver`, which is [not thread safe](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#q-is-webdriver-thread-safe), so you probably shouldn't use it in separate threads in production. In practice, it will probably work, as the actions you are performing are read only. Another possible reason to not use threads, is that the actions you are trying to parallelize are cpu-intensive, and in most such cases, python threads will not increase performance because of the GIL.

Multiprocessing, on the other hand, can indeed help you parallelize cpu-intensive work. But passing the browser object to each worker process (as you did) will not work, because the browser holds open files, sockets, and has it's own stateful driver instance. These can't be trivially duplicated and passed to another process. What you could do instead, is create a browser object in each worker, navigate to the page and perform you tasks on it afterwards.

#### Edit

To further improve execution time you can try:

1. Using locator methods other than `find_by_xpath`, it is inherently slow, as it traverses the whole DOM.
2. Using the `requests` library for getting html content and `lxml` for parsing it instead of using selenium, as the webdriver might cause some serious overhead.

Comment: Makes sense, My target here is to scan a webpage for the possible improvements. Is there any other tech stack you would suggest that can help improve the overall execution time

Comment: the reason I am using the selenium is  - I am more interested in how the webpage behaves when visited by a real end-user - for example how long a web page takes to load including the assets as JS, CSS - which sometimes takes a lot of time to load degrading the user experience.

the other approach I am thinking of is having a WebSocket updating each component and sending the data back to WebSockets as soon as the results are ready - thoughts?

Comment: any thoughts please?

Comment: This sounds like an entirely different question. You should post it separately